# Jenkins, global vars

Tags: variables, jenkins

There is the following code that works correctly (adds a global variable successfully), but the result of executing this code in the pipeline is always FAILED. I can't catch an error using try-catch - nothing is output to the pipeline console.
If I make code with def (lines are commented out), FAILED does not occur (the pipeline is green), but the code does not work (the variable is not added.
How do I find an error or make sure that the pipeline doesn't FAIL?

```groovy
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.*

try {
  /*
  Jenkins instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
  //jenkins = Jenkins.instance //this need script approve
  def globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
  def envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
  def newEnvVarsNodeProperty = null
  def envVars = null    
   */

  instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
  globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
  envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

  newEnvVarsNodeProperty = null
  envVars = null

  if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
    newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
    globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty)
    envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars()
  } else {
    envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()
  }
} catch(Exception ex) {
  println("Exception error: ${ex}")
}


envVars.put("sample_var", "Sample Groovy Global Var")
instance.save()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Copy-pasted code into a pipeline job, run it, build result is success, env var was added. Jenkins 2.229.

Comment: Freestyle project or Pipeline?

Comment: Pipeline project

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this (function) code (it doesn't work either):

```
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.*

@NonCPS
def add_global_var() {

instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

newEnvVarsNodeProperty = null
envVars = null

if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
  newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
  globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty)
  envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars()
} else {
  envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()
}

envVars.put("snapshot_id", "Sample Groovy Global Var 4")
instance.save()

}


pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'slave' } }

    stages {

        stage('Check global var') {

            steps {

                add_global_var()

            }

        }
    }
}
```